# HighCharts: How to draw a straight line in multiple axes like plotLines with fixed X-axis with different values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts for my project. I've used multiple axes for drawing the chart. What I want is there should be a straight line on fixed x-axis even though with different values.

I want to have something like plotLines which will be straight and fixed on the x-axis but still shows different values I put it.

Comment: So... why not just use a plot line? I see you have a plot line in there, but you have it set at 100000, on an axis that doesn't have any data associated with it that reaches 100000, so it will never display.  Which brings up the question - if these bars are all scaled differently, what could a plot line possibly show you?  The chart is already meaningless because the bars have no relation to each other. Marking a line that would completely arbitrarily cut across them would be just as meaningless, while pretending to show meaning.  FWIW

Comment: I can use plotLine but what I want is it to show the three values which I'm passing to it being vertically set. As you can see the other line I have with values 2000, 3000,4000 I want to keep those values and show them and just make that line straight passsing through the middle of the graph. It doesn't matter what I use i just have to make a line pass exactly vertical through the middle of the chart and show these values. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: agree with @jlbriggs , if your axis values are known you can get extreme.DataMax/2 and put this as value in plotLine  http://jsfiddle.net/73oq2nzc/10/  Since your values are random it might not be the correct solution.

Comment: Yes I know. But I still am required to do so. So is there anyway to do that? Just to make that line vertical in the middle and keep those values. Is there any solution?

Comment: If what your orange line is supposed to is Average per xAxis category data then having them connected with a straight line is absolutely meaningless as they are on different axis scales. I would question this requirement. Maybe doing a scatter point showing the average would make much more sense. Like: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/73oq2nzc/11/

Comment: @AkashKumar - if you want to plot it in the "middle" of the chart, the best way will be to use the renderer function to draw the line with a pixel value, rather than trying to navigate the convoluted triple axis set up with a plot line or a series. Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Comment: yes ok. but how do I show the values keeping it a straight vertical line?

Comment: how do you make sure three arbitrary values from three arbitrarily scaled axes are all in a straight line? The question alone should scream how bizarre a task this is. You could calculate what percentage of the total each point is in its respective category, and try to manipulate the axis extremes to plot them each in the same area...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create separate series to achieve that. I think it's simpler solution than playing around with renderer. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6wo5mzo4/

```
(function(H) {
  var seriesTypes = H.seriesTypes;

  seriesTypes.fakeLine = Highcharts.extendClass(seriesTypes.line);

  seriesTypes.fakeLine.prototype.translate = function() {
    var s = this;

    seriesTypes.line.prototype.translate.call(s);

    H.each(s.points, function(point) {
        point.plotY = s.chart.plotWidth / 2; // display in the middle - note: plotWidth, not plotHeight, because chart is inverted
    });
  }
})(Highcharts);
```

However, I still have doubts how useful such chart will be. I would also suggest to review the requirements.

Comment: Yes that's perfect! Thanks a LOT! Just a couple of things - 1. The graph is now covered with other gray lines how can I hide them. 2. The third value is not displayed on the vertical line. 3. Is there a way to increase the length of that line. 4. Also since this is a multiple axes graph I am not able to decrease the gap between these three bars how can I do that?

Comment: Yes I know all these comparisons don't make sense. But this is the task that I'm given and I have to do it. So I'm really thankful to you for your help.

Comment: 1) Remove `plotBorderWidth`. 2) Set `dataLabels.allowOverlap` to true 3) Set `x` values for your line series and min+max for xAxis 4) Change `pointWidth`. See demo with all changes: http://jsfiddle.net/6wo5mzo4/2/

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for all the help everything you mentioned works perfectly. but the pointWidth is just making the width of the columns smaller but the gap between them still remains very big. How can I decrease those. pointPadding or groupPadding also doesn't work.

Comment: `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` doesn't work because you have fixed `pointWidth`. You can remove that option. Anyway, for me `pointWidth` works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6wo5mzo4/3/ - just don't forget to **increase** `pointWidth` ;)

Comment: Yes sir, I want to keep the pointWidth fixed to 30 and still want the distance between the columns views, videos, subscribers very less.

Comment: Then decrease size of the chart: http://jsfiddle.net/6wo5mzo4/6/. I'm not sure what else could happen with your extra space..

Comment: Thank you sir. Thanks a lot for all your help. :)